# Turning a string into a function line in R

Tags: r

I am relatively new to R and I would like to do the following:
if I write a simple function as

```
fn<-function(K) K^2
```

and then compute `fn(10)`, I get 100.

Now if `K^2` is created somewhere as a string, `t1="K^2"`, then obviously my function does not work anymore since it does not take K as a variable.

How can I turn a string, a sequence of characters into a line in my function?

I don't want to use `eval(parse(text=t1))`, because I would like to use my function later in another function, say to find the gradient using `n1.grad(x0,fn)`.

Thanks,
Yasin

Comment: There is probably an alternative for this. This seems like bad practice and almost impossible to debug. It may also cause problems when you deal with multiple parameters/arguments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to use `eval ( parse())` but you do need to use `parse`, since translating text to syntactically acceptable (but unevaluated) parse trees is what parsing does. There are three components of a function that can be modified: arglist, body, and environment, and they each have an assignment function. Here we are only modifying the body with `body<-`:

```
?`function`
?`body<-`

fn <- function(K) {}
t1="K^2"
body(fn) <- parse(text=t1)
fn
#----------
function (K) 
K^2
```

And there is always:

```
fortunes::fortune(106)
```

Comment: just the usual reminder that if `t1` is from an untrusted source, you probably shouldn't be evaluating it as it could easily contain `unlink("/", TRUE, TRUE)` or some such.

Comment: Ouch. Or some `system()` call.

Comment: would you add an example for arglist and environment for my learning purpose. Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure I have already posted examples on SO for using `environment<-` (needed when hacking functions that call non-exported functions) Here's an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27671317/stargazer-model-names-instead-of-numbers/27672401#27672401 . For the arglist part, just following the links on the `?'function'` help page appears perfectly adequate. You should post a question if something is unclear after you have made a good faith effort to answer your own questions.

Comment: BondedDust, thanks so much for taking the time to answer my question! BrodieG, thanks for the reminder.