# Custom model names in Stargazer package for R

Tags: r, statistics, stargazer

I'm wondering how to get custom model names in the [stargazer](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stargazer/) package for R.

There is an option for `model.names` which can be set to `TRUE`or `FALSE`, but it does not support a vector or names such as `model.names = c('OLS','2SLS','GLS')`.

Is there any way to override the function to use custom names passed as parameters instead of reading the model names from the objects passed?

Comment: Not the solution you ask for, but the most expedient way is probably to just  name your models as you want them labeled. You can use backticks for non-standard names (like `\`2SLS\` <- model_2`)

Comment: Could you please clarify the syntax for this (renaming the models)? Not the backticks, but rather the way to modify the model name in the `lm()` object. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stargazer: model names instead of numbers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27671317/stargazer-model-names-instead-of-numbers)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Stargazer optionally includes the object names, so if you models are

```
m1 = lm(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars)
m2 = lm(mpg ~ wt + disp, data = mtcars)
```

You can do

```
stargazer(m1, m2, object.names = TRUE,
          column.labels = c("lab 1", "lab 2e"))
```

to get both custom labels and the object names, `m1` and `m2`. This can be usefully abused by using non-standard names matching the extra model names that you want

```
OLS = m1
`2SLS` = m2
    stargazer(OLS, `2SLS`, object.names = TRUE,
              column.labels = c("lab 1", "lab 2e"))
```

Though, unfortunately, the backticks are included in the output. (As an additional hack you could `capture.output()` and remove them with `gsub`).

The model names used by stargazer are not part of the model object, rather stargazer examines the model object and attempts to extract them. You can see the `.model.identify` function [on github](https://github.com/cran/stargazer/blob/e44f37e29537f5be9e7e6f0386cb98364150aa7d/R/stargazer-internal.R). You could attempt to `fixInNamespace` to adjust this, but I think a post-hoc hack is easier.

Comment: Thanks, I guess the `capture.output()` method is the way to go then!